# Scikit learn models gives weight to random variable? Should I remove features with less importance?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, random-forest, xgboost, feature-selection

I do some feature selection by removing correlated variables and backwards elimination. However, after all that is done as a test I threw in a random variable, and then trained logistic regression, random forest and XGBoost. All 3 models have the feature importance of the random feature as greater than 0. First, how can that be? Second, all models have it ranked toward the bottom, but it's not the lowest feature. Is this a valid step for another round of feature selection -i.e. remove all those who score below the random feature?

The random feature is created with

```
model_data['rand_feat'] = random.randint(100, size=(model_data.shape[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen, What random is the number you sample, but this random sampling can still generate a pattern by chance. I dont know whether you are doing classification or regression but lets consider the simple example of binary classification. We have class 1 and 0 and 1000 data point from each. When you sample a random number for each data point, it can happen that for example a majority of class 1 gets some value higher than 50, whereas majority of class 0 gets a random number smaller than 50.

So in the end effect, this might result into some pattern. So I would guess everytime you run your code the random feature importance changes. It is always ranked low because it is very unlikely that a good pattern is generated(e.g all 1s get higher than 50 and all 0s get lower than 50).

Finally, yes you should consider to drop the features with low value

Answer (score 0):

I agree with berkay's answer that a random variable can have patterns that are by chance associated to your outcome variable. Secondly, I will neither include random variable in model building nor as my filtering threshold because if random variable has by chance significant or nearly significant association to the outcome it will suppress the expression of important features of original data and you probably end up losing those important features.

Answer (score 0):

In early phase of model development I always include two random variables.

For me it is like a 'sanity check' since these are in effect junk variables or junk features.

If any of my features are worse in importance than the junk features then that is a warning sign that I need to look more carefully at the worth* of those features or to do some better feature engineering.

- For example what does theory suggest about the inclusion of those features?